# How do I analyze a pre & post test survey with Likert scale items?

Tags: r, statistics, analysis, survey, likert

A bit of context. 
1). I know all respondents answers to a pre-and-post survey after an hour long training session was conducted. 
2). I can also match all respondents pre and post answers. For example, I know respondent one's pre-survey answer to question 1 and post-survey answer to question 1 (both questions are the same). 
3). There are 14 questions in the pre-and-post survey that are all the same. The questions are all Likert scale items ranged from 1 to 4.
4). I would prefer to compare the overall results of the survey, but I am willing to go item-by-item. However, I would prefer not to go item-by-item.

What is the "best" way to statistically compare my pre-and-post surveys?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read info on asking questions with the R tag. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info  This may be a better question for Cross Validated or Data Science.  Stack overflow is focused on programing questions.

Comment: Hi JimStir! This is a good question, but not for this site. I'm voting to close it, but I expect it would be well received on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Clearly a question for CrossValidated. Can someone migrate it?